# Deploy play framework on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, playframework

Im using play framework 6.2/servlet 2.5, I generated the war and deployed it on tomcat 7/8/9 ( I tried all versions)
And Im getting same error:

```
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart 
Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute 
(listener) play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.Mode$.Prod()Lscala/Enumeration$Value;
    at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.<init>(Play2Server.scala:40)
    at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.<clinit>(Play2Server.scala)
    at play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.contextInitialized(GenericPlay2Servlet.scala:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 
> 16-Aug-2017 16:24:25.327 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log PlayServletWrapper 
> contextDestroyed
16-Aug-2017 16:24:25.327 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop 
Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte détruit (context destroyed) 
à l'instance de classe d'écoute play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$
    at play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.contextDestroyed(GenericPlay2Servlet.scala:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4858)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5474)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I know play 6.2 is not compatible, I want to go as much further as I can. Is this the end line ? I still have hope ...

Anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what do you mean is, you are trying to use [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin) with play 2.6. From the readme in that link, the play2-war-plugin doesn't support play version 2.5.x and I believe it also doesn't support 2.6.x yet. So try to test/develop using play 2.4.x. I would say it is end of the line for you if you insist to use play 2.6.x and current version of play2-war-plugin.

Comment: I looked in compiled classes using Java decompiler, I found the method Prod() , so I dont really understand ?